# Reverse requirements.txt

Tags: python, reverse, github-api, requirements.txt

How can I get a list of github repositories of python projects
with a particular dependency in the requirements.txt file?

This is sort of a "reverse requirements.txt" mapping

Comment: You'd have to search all repositories ever published that have a requirements.txt or setup.py file and parse those. Good luck with that, that'll take you a while!

Comment: Why did you want to have this information?

Comment: Lol true. I was looking for django projects and wanted to see a few example projects to see how they structure their code, and then this more general question came to mind, which prompted me to ask if there is any existing method

Comment: Try the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for "a few examples", then a Google search with both `site:` and `inurl:` restrictions might help out.  For example, [site:github.com inurl:requirements.txt django](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+inurl%3Arequirements.txt+django).

You could drop the `site:github.com` restriction, obviously, if you wanted to look everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. This is the most efficient method. Just learned the "inurl" key

Comment: Looks like the same works in duckduckgo.com, e.g. [site:github.com inurl:requirements.txt django](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Agithub.com+inurl%3Arequirements.txt+django&t=canonical&ia=web)

Comment: Funny enough, github released "dependency graphs", in which one can check all "dependent" projects. For example, to see all projects depending on django, check [Insights / Dependency graph / Dependents](https://github.com/django/django/network/dependents)

Comment: Actually, these are dependencies via `package.json` or `Gruntfile`, i.e. nodejs and ruby. The particular example I've been after was `django`. The github dependencies show `django` as a dependency for `nodejs` projects. That confuses me as django is a `python` web framework